# Error in Create Team Project From Visual Studio 2008 for TFS 2010

Tags: tfs

I can connect TFS 2010 Server from Visual Studio 2008 Explorer.
and connect with collection.

But when i go for Create Team Project from Visual Studio 2008 i got below error.

---

TF30172: You are trying to create a team project either without required permissions or with an older

version of Team Explorer. Contact your project administrator to check your permissions or to determine how

### to upgrade Team Explorer.

i had installed below software.
1 Visual Studio 2008 SP1
2 VS2008 forward Compatibility software for TFS 2010
3 TFS 20010 Install on Server 2008 R2 Server (64 bit) OS.
4 Plugin for install for Visual Studio 2008.

Please if any reply or solution please let me know.
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Like the error message says, you can't create a new team project for TFS 2010 from a 2008 client. If you don't have VS 2010, you can download Team Explorer 2010 from here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=329.

Comment: thank you for you reply. after vs2010explorer i can able to add new team project.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create team project by yourself you need to configure TFS server where you can add project without TFS Server you are not allowed.